# List of all listeners on channel

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

How is it possible to see all listeners on channel at some moment ? (I mean phoenix-js and client-side js code)

Something, like this:

```
channel.eventListeners = ['event1', 'event2'] ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found all I need in `channel.bindings`